# Sublimetext 2 and rails html.erb if then else issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, sublimetext2

Love Sublime text 2, but somehow can't get it to do 'if then else' properly within an html.erb template.
It correctly identifies the files as 'HTML (Rails)', but when I do 'if' followed by tab

I get:

```
<?php if (condition): ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

I've seen this reported a few other places, but not sure how to fix as new to Sublimetext.
Any tips much appreciated

Comment: Looks like you have it set to be generating php, is there anything in settings or options to set ruby/rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have php autocomplete there.

Install ruby and rails plugins for rails development.

More at http://linuxrails.blogspot.com/2012/05/sublime-text-2-setup-for-rails.html

Answer (score 2):

I added a couple of custom snippets to cover if/elsif/else in erb files.

if-erb.sublime-snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<% if ${1:true} -%>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>if</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
    <description>if (ERB)</description>
</snippet>
```

elsif-erb.sublime-snippet

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<% elsif ${1:true} -%>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>elsif</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
    <description>elsif (ERB)</description>
</snippet>
```

else-erb.sublime-snippet

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<% else -%>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>else</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.ruby</scope>
    <description>else (ERB)</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've filed a pull request for these on the ERB-Snippets package: https://github.com/matthewrobertson/ERB-Sublime-Snippets/pull/4

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way i could make it work was by deleting the php snippets and adding some of my own.
Steps:
1- Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages`.
2- Go inside `PHP` folder.
3- Delete the else/elsif snippets.
4- Create your own like the following example:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
    <% else %>
  ]]></content>
<tabTrigger>else</tabTrigger>
<scope>text.html - source</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. After adding the ERB snippets package, I could get "if" to complete to ERB, but a menu would pop up asking me to choose between ERB and PHP. Any idea why the <scope>source.php</source> in the PHP snippets fails to keep the PHP out of my "HTML (Rails)" mode?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem is with the `text.html - source` scope and not the `source.php`. Any idea how to scope PHP's HTML snippets so they only appear in "HTML (PHP)" and not "HTML (Rails)"? Making it `text.html - source.php` didn't help.